# Configuring React Router v4 in Nginx behind a path

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I am trying to host my react app with `BrowserRouter` v4 and this is my nginx configuration.

```
        location /abc/ {
                alias /home/website/build/;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /abc/index.html;
        }
```

This is my Router

```
<App>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/images' component={Images} />
        <Route exact path='/videos' component={Videos} />
        <Route path="/other" component={Other} />
        <Route component={Contact} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </App>
```

However, when I try to access it through http://www.example.com/abc/ it returns a 404 error. May I know what is the right way to configure?

Comment: does this work? `try_files $uri/../`

Comment: You are creating a js bundle of your app and putting that in index file. Is this the way you're doing ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And I have fixed the homepage in package.json since I am using create-react-app

Comment: @cherhan, Did you solve the problem? I have the same problem.